# No preview rows found error in Pentaho

Tags: insert, pentaho, data-warehouse, fact-table

I have created the below transformation in Pentaho in which i am trying to insert data into fact table which is `SSSALES` table. When i click on `SSSALES` step and run a preview for this step then i am getting error as `No preview rows found error in Pentaho`. I am very much new to pentaho and this is the first time i am using tool. I dont know how to debug the issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have rows to preview for all of the input steps?

Comment: I will suggest you to preview incrementally instead of directly jumping on to the target step. I think one of your join is not throwing any output.